# TSQL Determine every other Friday from a "seed" date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datediff, dateadd

Greetings StackOverflow Wizards.

SQL datetime calculations always give me trouble.  I am trying to determine if an employee's hiredate fell between the last payday of that month and the first of the next month. (I.e. did they get a paycheck in their hire month.

Knowns:

- I know our paydays are every other Friday.
- I know 01/02/1970 was a Payday, and that date precedes the longest
  active employee we have.
- I know the hire date of each active employee (pulled from table).
- I know (can calculate) the first of the month following the hire
  date.

What I cannot seem to wrap my head around is how to use that seed date (01/02/1970) with datediff, dateadd, datepart, etc. to determine if there is a pay date between the hire date in question and the first of the following month.

In pseudo-code, here is what I'm trying to do:

```
declare @seedDate datetime = '01/02/1970' -- Friday - Payday seed date from which to calculate
declare @hireDate datetime = '09/26/2008'  -- this date will actually be pulled from ServiceTotal table
declare @firstOfMonth datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @hireDate) + 1, 0) -- the first of the month following @hireDate
declare @priorPayDate datetime  -- calculate the friday payday immediately prior to @firstOfMonth


if @priorPayDate BETWEEN @hireDate AND @firstOfMonth
    begin
        -- do this
    end
else
    begin
        -- do that
    end
```

Using the hard-coded @hireDate above, and the @seedDate to determine every-other-Friday paydays, I know that there was a payday on 9/19/2008 and not another one until 10/03/2008, so the boolean above would be FALSE, and I will "do that" rather than "do this."  How do I determine the value of @priorPayDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a `DATEDIFF` for days between your @seedDate and @firstOfMonth will give you a total number of days, which you can [modulus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) by number of days between pay periods (14) to get number of days from the last pay period to the @firstOfMonth.  You'll run into problems when the 1st is a payday (e.g. next month), which makes a `CASE` statement necessary:

```
DECLARE @priorPayDate DATETIME 
SET @priorPayDate = CASE
                      WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, @seedDate, @firstOfMonth) % 14 = 0 
                        THEN DATEADD(dd, -14, @firstOfMonth)
                      ELSE DATEADD(dd, -(DATEDIFF(dd, @seedDate, @firstOfMonth) % 14), @firstOfMonth)
                    END
```

Comment: stubaker, this is working beautifully.  I cannot adequately express my appreciation for you wrapping your mind around what had me stumped.

Answer (score 2):

In all my databases where there is a lot going on with dates I create a table with colums for date,day, weekday,month,weeknr,dayof month, etc etc. I then use a procedural programming language or a bunch of handwritten sql to populate this table with every day for a large range of years say 1970 to 2200.

I pack this table 100% and index it heavily. You can then simply join any date to this table and do complex date stuff with simple where clause. So basically you pre calculate a helper table. maybe in you case you add a column to the date helper table with friday since seed column.

hope that makes sense.

Comment: That is where my mind was headed, even though I don't really want to do it that way.  I still may have to if I am unable to make stubaker's suggestion work for me.  Thanks for generously chiming in!